# Mockery throw on first then return value on second call

Tags: php, phpunit, mockery

```
$client = Mockery::mock();
$client->shouldReceive('send')->andThrow($error)->andReturn(true);
```

Unfortunately it only returns true but not throw the exception first. How do I throw an exception on first call then return value on second call of the method?

**EDIT**:

This works if I manually edit `Mockery\Expectation.php` and set `$_throw
 = true`.

```
$client->shouldReceive('send')->twice()->andReturn($error, true);
```

Answer (score 37, accepted):

```
$client->shouldReceive('send')->once()->andThrow($error);
$client->shouldReceive('send')->once()->andReturn(true);
```